# How to keep the api alive even if a datasource is not available on loopback 3?

Tags: javascript, rest, loopbackjs

I have a doubt about the data sources:
Context: Currently I'm working on a project where my API uses two datasources: **A** and **B**.

Sometimes the datasource **B** has troubles and is not available while **A** is always available.
When **B** is not available the whole web service collapses.

My question: Is there any way to program the api to keep it working with the part that only evolves the datasource **A** when the datasource **B** is not accessible?

Note: I'm working with Loopback 3

Comment: I think you need to provide more details about what kind of datasources you use and what is exactly the problem you see with your API. We use loopback too and we have multiple datasources, the API never crashes even if one of the datasource is not available. So what do you mean by "keep the API alive" and why it does not stay available in your case? 

The only problem I can think of may occur when you try to restart the API while one of the datasources is unavailable. In this case if you have some boot logic based on that datasource it may fail and the API will not start correctly.

Comment: Is was exactly that, the API restarted when one of the datasources was unavailable, it works when adds the "lazyConnect": true to the datasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lazyConnect:true` Will defer connection until you query a model attached to it, and send the client an error without crashing the server if the connection fails.

```
  "myDatasource": {
    "name": "myDatasource",
    "host": "ds.com",
    "database": "db",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "connector": "postgres",
    "lazyConnect": true
  },
```

> My question: Is there any way to program the api to keep it working with the part that only evolves the datasource A when the datasource B is not accessible?

You can use your datasource's events to know when to swap models.  Here is something I tested briefly.

`server/boot/swap.js`

```
function swapModelDatasource(app, model, ds) {
    const name = model.name;
    app.deleteModelByName(name);
    const m = app.model(ds.createModel(name, model.definition.properties, {
        settings: model.settings,
        relations: model.settings.relations,
        acls: model.settings.acls
    }));
}

module.exports = app => {
    const ds1 = app.datasources.aws;
    const m = app.models.Node;
    ds1.on('connected', () => swapModelDatasource(app, m, ds1));
}
```